# React-Redux - Create a Search Filter

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, react-redux

i need help to make a Search Filter in my app. Its a simple app, used for study purposes.

The objective is to create a search filter. i have the **state** in search_bar container and i think i need to pass it as props to my work_list container. but i dont know how to do that. from that phase i will make it something like this.

**work_list.js**

```
renderWork() {

    let filteredWorks = this.props.works.filter((work) => {
      return work.title.indexOf(this.state.init) !== -1;
    }
    );


    return filteredWorks.map((work) => {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{work.title}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  }
```

I dont know if the logic is right. Need Help.

**app.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SearchBar from '../containers/search_bar';
import WorkList from '../containers/work_list.js';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar/>
        <WorkList/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**search_bar.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class SearchBar extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { init: '' };
    this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  onInputChange(event) {
    this.setState({ init: event.target.value });
  }

  onFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form
        onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}
        className="input-group">
        <input
          className="form-control"
          placeholder = "Procurar Trabalho"
          onChange={this.onInputChange}
          value={this.state.init} />
        <span className="input-group-btn">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary">Pesquisar</button>
        </span>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

**work_list.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchWork } from '../actions/index';

class WorkList extends Component {

  renderWork() {
    return this.props.works.map((work) => {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{work.title}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table className="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.renderWork() }
        </tbody>
      </table>

    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    works: state.works
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(WorkList);
```

**My Reducers**

**reducer_work.js**

```
export default function () {
  return [
    { title: 'Mirististica' },
    { title: 'Vet' }
  ];
}
```

**index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import MostrarTrabalhos from './reducer_work';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    works : MostrarTrabalhos
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**Thank You !**

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify what you’re asking.

Comment: Im new to React And Redux, sometimes is dificult to make the questions...Thanks for the advice. I will try to reformulate.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like your code is missing some key elements for Redux to work.  You need to dispatch a Redux action when your search input changes that will in turn update the store.  Right now you're merely setting the local state of `SearchBar` when the input changes.  Secondly, your reducer doesn't modify the state, it's always returning the same array.

Something along these lines.

Your actions file might look like this:

```
export const SEARCH = 'SEARCH';

export function search(value) {
  return {type: SEARCH, value};
}
```

Then your reducer might look like this:

```
import {SEARCH} from './actions';

const initialState = {contents: ['Mirististica', 'Vet'], value: '', works: []};

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case SEARCH: {
      const {value} = action;
      const works = state.contents.filter((val) => val.includes(value));
      return {...state, value, works};
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Then in your `SearchBar`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {search} from './actions';

class SearchBar extends Component {
  render() {
    const {search, value} = this.props;

    return (
        <input
          className="form-control"
          placeholder = "Procurar Trabalho"
          onChange={(e) => search(e.target.value)}
          value={value} />
    );
  }
} 

function mapStateToProps({works}) {
  return {value: works.value};
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({search}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```

Your `WorkList` component merely needs to listen for changes to `works` in the Redux store.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class WorkList extends Component {
  render() {
    const {works} = this.props;

    return (
      <table className="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{works.map((work) => <tr key={work}><td>{work}</td></tr>)}</tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({works}) {
  return {
    works: works.works
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(WorkList);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, im new to Redux and React. im trying to learn, and i will study the solution you gave me. :) there is a TypeO on you code, i cannot solve it, could you help me ?

Comment: <tbody>{works.map((work) => <tr key={work}> <td>{work}</td> </tr>}</tbody>

Comment: Sorry, I missed the closing `)` on the `map` function.  I've updated it.

Comment: It works :) . thank you very much for the help. i understand i have to study a lot more. :) :) !! Thank you !!

Comment: @PatrickGrimard why you have not used selector in this approach.