# troubles with react-redux search filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

It is my first react-redux project (list of courses) and I have some troubles with redux. I need to do the search by course name, I based my code on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40342381/react-redux-create-a-search-filter) I can see the action in redux-devtool, but not on ui. Please help me to understand what I am doing wrong

```
    //action    
    export function search (value) {
        return {type: SEARCH, value};
    }

    //reducer
    import { COURSES } from '../../constants';
    const initialState = COURSES;    
    export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
        switch(action.type) {
            case SEARCH: {
                const {value} = action;
                const course = state.filter((val) => val.includes(value));
                return {...state, value, course};
            }
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }

//search component

    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {connect} from 'react-redux';
    import {deleteCourse, search} from '../../redux/actions';

    class SearchInput extends Component {
        render() {
            const {search, value} = this.props;
            return (
                <div className={classes.SearchInput}>
                    <input
                        placeholder='Search'
                        onChange={(e) => search(e.target.value)}
                        value={value}
                    />
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    export default connect (state => ({
        courses: state.courses,
    }), {search})(SearchInput);


//Courses Component
import Form from '../Form/Form';
    import { deleteCourse, search } from '../../redux/actions';

    const Courses = ({ courses, deleteCourse }) => {
        console.log(courses)
        return (
            <div className={classes.Courses}>
                <SearchInput />
                <Button title='Add course' />
                <CourseList
                    courses={courses}
                    deleteCourse={deleteCourse}
                    search={search}
                />
                <Form />
            </div>
        )
    }

    export default connect (state => ({
        courses: state.courses,
    }), {deleteCourse})(Courses);
```

[image-from-redux-devtool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1j6L.jpg)

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to ask a question not ask people to debug your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things that may be causing it

```
export function search (value) {
  return {type: SEARCH, value};
}
```

Unless you didn't add your entire action code above (which judging by the dev tool photo may be the case) you're passing an undefined variable as type

```
 import { COURSES } from '../../constants';
    const initialState = COURSES;    
    export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
        switch(action.type) {
            case SEARCH: {
                const {value} = action;
                const course = state.filter((val) => val.includes(value));
                return {...state, value, course};
            }
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
```

In your reducer it looks like your initial state is an array (since you're able to filter it directly),  but then you iterate that array as properties of a return object.

```
const initialState = {courses: [], value: '', matches: []}

const matches = state.courses.filter((val) => val.includes(value));

return {...state, matches: matches};
```

Your initial state structure shouldn't be restructured on a return; instead it should look like the above, with matches filtered from state.courses. Storing search value in state also doesn't appear to be of any use, so it can be removed.

Overall, I don't think it's necessary to do search through redux as the parent component can manage its own rendering. You just need to create a state property to filter courses passed in by redux connect.

See working example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-boyd-9cgfo?file=/src/App.js